# How to use Korg Monopoly's "Trig In" port to trigger appegiator -

Tags: midi

How to use a pre MIDI Korg Monopoly's "Trig In" port to trigger appegiator - in a MIDI studio. I know its an old analogue device but with superb sound generation possibilities. I would like to trigger the appegiator from my DAW (Presonus) if possible?

Answer (score 1):

So a v-trig is a [gate](https://www.synthesizers.com/gates.html) (trigger) port and an s-trig is an inversion of that without the highside voltage. You should be able to trigger it with a square wave from an LFO in your DAW using a cable setup like this one developed by [Doepfler](http://www.doepfer.de/faq/gen_faq.htm). The gate signal from the DAW would be converted into the s-trig signal this way:

[image: Gate to S-trig]

Comment: Thank you for the schematic - it sure looks like a solution. If the components can be built into the connector it will be perfect. I hope that the square wave will trigger the Korg - keen to build it and find out.